# Whats wrong with this query? i am getting null result

Tags: mysql, sql, right-join

```
SELECT `acart`.`order_number` AS `admin_order_number`, 
       `acart`.`user_id` AS `admin_user_id`, 
       `acart`.`created_by` AS `admin_created_by`, 
       `rcart`.`order_number` AS `renew_order_number`, 
       `rcart`.`user_id` AS `renew_user_id`, 
       `rcart`.`created_by` AS `renew_created_by`, 
       `scart`.`order_number` AS `shopping_order_number`,
       `scart`.`user_id` AS `shopping_user_id`,
       `scart`.`created_by` AS `shopping_created_by` 
FROM `cdp_order_transaction_master` AS `master`
LEFT JOIN `cdp_admin_shopping_cart` AS `acart` 
    ON `acart`.`order_number`=`master`.`order_number` 
LEFT JOIN `cdp_renew_cart` AS `rcart` 
    ON `rcart`.`order_number`=`master`.`order_number` 
LEFT JOIN `cdp_shopping_cart` AS `scart` 
    ON `scart`.`order_number`=`master`.`order_number` 
WHERE master.order_number IS NULL
```

Let me explain my problem,if the order is successfull then it will goes to cdp_order_transaction_master table and any other 3 table (cdp_admin_shopping_cart,cdp_renew_cart,cdp_shopping_cart) depending on the situation but if the order fails then it will not go to cdp_order_transaction_master table and remain in other tables,
    so i want the failed order which is not present in cdp_order_transaction_master and can present in any other tables(cdp_admin_shopping_cart,cdp_renew_cart,cdp_shopping_c‌​art)

Comment: please read this before posting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You sure you don't want `WHERE master.order_number IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: yes i want only NULL, i edit my question for better understanding,please read it once.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE master.order_number IS NULL`

This is your primary table, and the join condition for all other tables are on this column.

You are trying to join null to null

Based on your comment, try:

```
select 'cdp_admin_shopping_cart' as `err_table`, a1.order_number
from cdp_admin_shopping_cart a1
where not exists (select 1 from cdp_order_transaction_master a2 where a2.order_number = a1.order_number)

union all

select 'cdp_renew_cart' as `err_table`, a1.order_number
from cdp_renew_cart a1
where not exists (select 1 from cdp_order_transaction_master a2 where a2.order_number = a1.order_number)

union all

select 'cdp_shopping_c‌​art' as `err_table`, a1.order_number
from cdp_shopping_c‌​art a1
where not exists (select 1 from cdp_order_transaction_master a2 where a2.order_number = a1.order_number)
```

Comment: let me explain my problem,if the order is successfull then it will goes to cdp_order_transaction_master table and any other 3 table (cdp_admin_shopping_cart,cdp_renew_cart,cdp_shopping_cart) depending on the situation but if the order fail then it will not go to cdp_order_transaction_master table and remain in other tables

Comment: so i want the failed order which is not present in cdp_order_transaction_master and can present in any other tables(cdp_admin_shopping_cart,cdp_renew_cart,cdp_shopping_cart)